# CREATE FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2012

SSMS keeps giving me a system error:

> Incorrect Syntax: CREATE FUNCTION must be the only statement in the batch

I don't know what I'm doing wrong :( please help

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx_avgVacationHrs 
    (@whatgender varchar(5))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
        (SELECT AVG(VacationHours) AS AvgVacationhrsbyGender
         FROM HumanResources.Employee
         WHERE Gender = @whatgender)
END

SELECT dbo.fx_avgVacationHrs('F')
```

Comment: Add a `GO` after the `END`.

Comment: i figured out the problem... it was because I was putting an entire select statement on the select variable rather than declaring a variable and then asking for the return of that variable

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if there was any statements before the script you posted.

Can you try to put ";" before CREATE FUNCTION statement?  If it stopped complaining that's means you were having other statement before this section.

Please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT* FROM HumanResources.Employee

CREATE FUNCTION  fn_GetUserID

( @businessentityID int)
RETURNS varchar(30)
AS 
BEGIN
        DECLARE @UserID varchar(30)
        SET @UserID =  (SELECT SUBSTRING(LoginID, CHARINDEX('\', LoginID)+1, 10) 
        FROM HumanResources.Employee
        WHERE   BusinessEntityID = @businessentityID)

```
    RETURN @UserID
```

END